# How to rdc to a particular machine that is member of a TS Farm?

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-services

I created a Terminal Services farm comprising of 3 TS hosts (say, TS1, TS2 and TS3) running Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise, a TS Connection broker and a TS Gateway for the purpose of hosting a windows application as a TS RemoteApp. The setup works just fine. Now, I want to do some further configuration changes on a particular TS host, say TS2 and not on any other TS host. I try to rdc to TS2 but I find myself getting connected to a randomly chosen TS host (sometimes TS1, sometimes TS2, and at other times, TS3). I think rdc connection is also going via the Connection Broker that is forwarding me to a TS host it decides is best. Is there a way I can deterministically connect to a particular TS host using rdc? I don't have option to login locally on a TS host as the entire setup is hosted in a remote data center. I think this is a very common scenario and must have a straight forward solution. It could be as easy as doing rdc to Connection Broker server and disabling it for a while, but I don't know how to do that too. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com or serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

One can use `mstsc /console`, or on more recent client versions use `mstsc /admin` to deterministically rdc to a particular member of a load balanced TS Farm.